# google analytics API, how to extract pageviews for a specific page?

Tags: api, google-analytics, analytics

Google Analytics API: how to extract pageviews for a specific page?

I tried using something like

```
ga:pagePath=~page.php%3fid%3d44 (page.php?id=44)
```

but it doesn't seem to work... I get "no results found" where I have 20 pageviews for sure

**UPDATE**

I think I found the solution

```
ga:pagePath==/website/page.php?id=44
```

for some reason I had to include the complete path and ==

Comment: You don't need the complete path, but you do need to use valid filter operators. I'm not sure what you were trying to do with the '~' in your original query. Anyways, here is the full list of filter operators available for use when requesting filtered data back from the Google Analytics Data API:
[http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDataFeed.html#filterOperators](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDataFeed.html#filterOperators)

Comment: if you found a solution, post it as answer and set it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

To use a partial path to match for a page in filters you should use

`ga:pagePath=@page.php?id=44`

`=@` tells `ga` to match a substring.

What you were originally using was incorrect for this.

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is that you put the hex version of the ? and = characters into your query, which doesn't match how Analytics stores the page paths. If you change these to the normal characters it should work:

```
ga:pagePath=~page.php?id=44
```

Your other solution should work as well but is a bit more inflexible in case you wanted to tweak the query to return other pages.

Comment: When  you send the requests to the Analytics API, they have to be encoded.